# Determine all $k$-critical graphs with $k\ge 3$ such that $G-v$ is $(k-1)$-critical $\forall v \in V(G)$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Okay, so the proof for this needs to be in two parts.  I believe the answer to be $K_k$ (the complete graph on k vertices).  I can show that if $G=K_k$ then $G$ is $k$-critical and $G-v$ is $(k-1)$ critical for all $v \in V(G)$.  This is good, but I must also show that if $G$  is $k$-critical and $G-v$ is $(k-1)$-critical then $G=K_k$.  This last part is really throwing me, and also makes me question whether my hypothesis is correct.  How can I go about showing this?  Should I use induction or possibly contradiction?

Edit:  I wanted to include what is meant by k-critical.  I mean colorwise k-critical.  That is, a graph $G$ is k-critical if $\chi (G) = k$ and $\chi (G-v) = k-1$ for all $v \in V(G)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $G$ is a solution that is not complete.
Let $\chi(G)=k$.
Then you can find two nonadjacent vertices $x$ and $y$. $G-x$ is $k-1$-critical, so you can find a proper $k-2$-coloring in $G-x-y$.

But now you can color $x$ and $y$ with the same color, because they are not adjacent, and you have found a $k-1$-coloring for $G$. Contradiction.

Comment: Took me a second to understand the argument, but yes, I like this very much.  Sweet and simple.

Comment: @Leen Droogendijk at the point you say $x$ and $y$ are non-adjacent and have the same color, can you say that the proper subgraph $H=G-x$ has the same chromatic of $G$ because you still have $y$ with same color to $x$ so no color is removed, since $\chi(H)=\chi(G)$ this contradict the definition of $k-critical$ that every proper subgraph $H$ must have $\chi(H)<\chi(G)$, $G$ is not $k-critical$ if $G$ is non-complete

Comment: @Diane Vanderwaif yeah, that makes sense

Comment: I am sorry, Diane, I do not understand you. In fact I cannot decide if you are asking a question or making a statement. But user3440448 seems to understand you, so there is no need for me to answer?

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk My question is, do I need the part " $G−x$ is $k−1$-critical, so you can find a proper $k−2$-coloring in $G−x−y$"? Because as you say you can color $x$ and $y$ the same and got $G$ has $k-1$ coloring, this is already a contradiction because a $k-critical$ graph can't have $k-1$ coloring. Am I correct?

Comment: @Diane Vanderwaif: I think I understand you now. You *do* need that part, because in general you cannot claim that you can give $x$ and $y$ the same color, even if they are not adjacent. Consider a $C_5$ and add two chords from one vertex. The two vertices of degree 2 are not adjacent, but you cannot give them the same color. Did I understand you now?

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk yes, you understand me perfectly. I just want to make sure I don't left out anything important. Thank you very much.